# Jupiter leverage is not working at all

Tags: exchanges

I tried trading on Jupiter Perps. However, the leverage is not applied. I used x10 on 10$ and 1% growth gave me 10 cents profit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked the jupiter support instead